# Call back not being called in scrapy

Tags: callback, scrapy

I am trying out scrapy's rules/link extractors.

The css under "restrict_css" is correct and i can retrieve the links using response.css in scrapy shell, but for some reason when i run this in a spider uner rules and link extractors the parse_product callback function is not called.

```
rules=(
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css='a.i-next')),

    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css='div.product-image-wrapper>a'),
         callback='parse_product'),
)

def parse_product(self, response):

    print("Print anything for testing")
    return
```

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What page are you crawling?

Comment: allowed_domains = ['http://www.orsay.com/de-de/']
    start_urls = ['http://www.orsay.com/de-de/']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your start_urls match none of the rules. The first rule is for next page and second rule is for products right? but your start urls doesn't point to products category, just the landing page. You either need start directly from products listing page url, like: http://www.orsay.com/de-de/neuheiten/t-shirts/tops.html

Or add additional rule to find product listing pages.

Comment: Thanks that helped. Silly mistake :)

Comment: @AhmadAshraf great, don't forget to click accept answer to the left of the answer if you have your issue solved :)